# How to plot an image from a series of bits inPython?

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-classification, visualization

I am given a dataset of 0s and 1s for some handwritten letters (below is a series for one image) and i'd like to visualize them in python. How can this be achieved?

`'000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000000001111000000000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000000000001111000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000000011111100000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111110000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000111111011111100000000000000000001111100111110000000000000000000111111000111110000000000000000001111100001111110000000000000000011111000001111100000000000000001111110000011111100000000000000011111000000111111100000000000000111110000000111111000000000000011111100000001111110000000000000111110000000001111110000000000001111100000000011111100000000000111111000000000011111100000000001111110000000000111111110000000011111100000001111111111111100000111111111111111111111111111100011111111111111111111111111111000111111111111111111111111111100001111111111111110000011111100000011111100000000000000111111000000111110000000000000001111110000011111100000000000000001111110000111110000000000000000011111100001111100000000000000000011111000111111000000000000000000111110001111110000000000000000001111110011111100000000000000000011111100111110000000000000000000011111001111100000000000000000000111110011111000000000000000000001111101111110000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000001111111110000000000000000000000001110'`

do i need to take it octet by octet to get a pixel value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use at least these two options:

- PIL library:

  ```
  from PIL import Image

  img = Image.new('1', (width, height)) #width and height of the original image
  data=[int(x) for x in x]  #x being your array
  img.putdata(data)
  img.save('my_handwritten_number.png')
  img.show()
  ```

You can see here an example with the whole process, from reading a hand written image file through converting it to an array and displaying it again to an image:

[image]

```
import numpy as np 

np_img=np_img.reshape(28900, )

width = np.sqrt(len(np_img))

from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('1', (int(width), int(width)))
data=[int(np_img) for np_img in np_img]
img.putdata(data)
img.save('my_hand_written_digit.png')
img.show()
```

getting as a result this reconstructed digit:

[image]

nevertheless, I see your array is a 1D array whose square root is not an integer, so it seems it does not come from an square image; you need to be able to convert it to a matrix (via the Image.new method). 
If I do it with your array, this is what I get:

[image]

- another option you have is with Keras:

  ```
  import tensorflow.keras as keras 

  keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(np_img.reshape(170, 170, 1), 
  data_format=None, scale=True, dtype=None)
  ```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, the PIL lib gets the job done perfectly! You are right, the images are not square, in fact, each one has different size. And when i use Image.new with a bigger size than the actual one, i already get a distorted image (like the one in your example). Is there a way i can turn all these 1D arrays into matrices of the same size, without distorting the images?